# How to show more than 5 items in Recently Viewed Products in Magento

Tags: magento

I encountered so much problems with limit in showing recently viewed products in magento

There is standard template for showing Recently viewed ones in magento

Its location is here

> template/reports/product_viewed.phtml

There is one line of getting Recently Viewed Products
It looks as:

> $_products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts()

But It returns only 5 last viewed elements

How can I increase LIMIT ? In my case I need to show last 7 products

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Go to your Magento backend:

```
System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Recently Viewed/Compared Products
```

and change `Default Recently Viewed Products Count`. It's default set to 5 but you can change it to whatever you want.

Comment: Gegard ! Thanks a lot
Precise answer

Comment: Is this setting for admin side "Most recent viewed Product " please confirm. I trying to change but not effect on admin side report .

Answer (score 0):

While creating a widget, go to:

Widget options > Number of Products to display > Select number of products you want to display